# Problems using Python logical operators with 0

Tags: python

Picking up a tip from someone else on this site, I've been using logical operators to express conditional logic in list comprehension as a shortcut to using full for loops with if statements.

For example, if I had a list [1, 0, 0, 1, 1] that I wanted to turn into ["Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes"] I could do it like this:

```
original = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
new = [((x==1) and "Yes") or "No" for x in original]
```

The problem I have is that I get some very strange results when I use the logical operators with 0 in this way. The results occur regardless of whether I'm using list comprehension or not.

These:

```
print((True and 1.0) or "Wrong")
print((True and -1.0) or "Wrong")
print((True and "1.0") or "Wrong")
print((True and 1) or "Wrong")
```

Correctly (I think) output:

```
1.0
-1.0
1.0
1
```

However these:

```
print((True and 0) or "Wrong")
print((True and 0.0) or "Wrong")
```

Output:

```
Wrong
Wrong
```

I think that Python is implicitly converting both 0 and 0.0 to a boolean False, and any other value of any other type to True

Can someone confirm whether:
a. This is the case and/or
b. Is there a way to achieve what I'm after in list comprehension another way (with a lamda or something)

Many thanks
Chris

Comment: Just use the ternary `<value> if <condition> else <value>` inline syntax.

Comment: I don't understand what you're actually trying to do with ``0`` and logical operators that's not working as you want.  Your "sample" code up at the top works fine, of course.  Could you provide a sample that's not doing what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes `0` is returning a false in your short-circuit evaluation (you can test via `bool(0)` which returns a `false` ). I think this is a lot simpler:

```
new = ["yes" if x else "no" for x in list]
```

Comment: Yep. the `a if b else c` construct is the better tool for the job here.

Comment: Thanks Amber! I've updated my answer. This is much clearer. Edit: oops.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know you could do that

Answer (score 1):

The following values are interpreted as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. (See the **nonzero**() special method for a way to change this.)

excerpted from http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: Thanks - I've answered both my questions now :)